# IE Errors with jQuery Code

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

This occurs in IE8, and IE7. I am not coding to support IE6, so that doesn't concern me.

I have this simple line of jQuery code that runs fine on other browsers, but on IE, I get the error..

> **Object doesn't support this property or method**

I have marked the offending line.

```
    options.button.click(function (e) {
        options.menu.is(':visible') ? lift() : drop(); // works fine.
        e.stopPropogation(); // error occurs here.
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spelling error?

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

Documentation: [jQuery API event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Comment: ... fml. I cannot ... I'm just ... let's forget this ever happened.

Comment: @Stacey - ;-) Haha...before you forget, would you mind marking my answer as accepted? Glad I could help you!

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions, we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?

Answer (score 1):

try to use 'event' instead of 'e'

```
event.stopPropogation();
```